# "float" text (with border) right AND stay in it's parent div

Tags: html, css

thanks for any help in advance.
I guess it's something simple but i don't get it.
The button should be at the bottom right and the border should not going bonkers.

I said float in the Headline but thats just to clarify things. I'm pretty sure thats not how i should do this.

Heres my HTML:

```
<div class="boxtest1">
    <div id="sbts">
        TeamSpeak³
    </div>
    <div id="sbtsinfo">
        some text here <br> some more text <br> some more text
    </div>
    <div id="sbtsbutton">
        <a href="ts3server://xxxxx">Join</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.boxtest1 {
  height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 32px;
  width: 38%;
  border: 4px solid #ff5857;
  border-radius: 0px 40px 0px 40px;
  background: rgba(255,88,87,0.2);
}
#sbts {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #BDBDBD;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted #ff5857;
}
#sbtsinfo {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #BDBDBD;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted #ff5857;
}
#sbtsbutton {
  direction: rtl;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 2px solid #ff5857;
  border-radius: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
}
#sbtsbutton a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #BDBDBD;
}
#sbtsbutton:hover {
  background: #228822;
}
```

> http://codepen.io/6P14y3r/pen/ZaEKag

Sorry if my english is bad ^.^

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean, but if you're asking about problem with bottom right corner when button slightly overlaps container - you simply need to make `border-radius` values for container and button to match. So `#sbtsbutton { border-radius: 0px 20px 0px 40px; }` should fix this issue.

Comment: thats not my problem - the border of the button takes the whole width of the parent container but should only be as big as the "Join" text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you should add display: table in .boxtest1 and float: right: right in #sbtsbutton

```
.boxtest1 {
  height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 32px;
  width: 38%;
  border: 4px solid #ff5857;
  border-radius: 0px 40px 0px 40px;
  background: rgba(255,88,87,0.2);
  display: table;
}
#sbtsbutton {
  direction: rtl;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 2px solid #ff5857;
  border-radius: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you add `overflow: hidden;` to the parent's CSS and `clear: both;
float: right` to the child's CSS it should solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

If i am sure you are trying to get border same as the join text,
please see this snippet,

```css
.boxtest1 {
  height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 32px;
  width: 38%;
  border: 2px solid #ff5857;
  border-radius: 0px 40px 0px 40px;
  background: rgba(255,88,87,0.2);
}
#sbts {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #BDBDBD;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted #ff5857;
}
#sbtsinfo {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #BDBDBD;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted #ff5857;
}
#sbtsbutton {
  direction: rtl;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 2px solid #ff5857;
  border-radius: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
}
#sbtsbutton a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #BDBDBD;
}
#sbtsbutton:hover {
  background: #228822;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxtest1">
    <div id="sbts">
        TeamSpeak³
    </div>
    <div id="sbtsinfo">
        some text here <br> some more text <br> some more text
    </div>
    <div id="sbtsbutton">
        <a href="ts3server://xxxxx">Join</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you even change something? :)

Comment: oh yeah,
i misunderstood this comment  :: thats not my problem - the border of the button takes the whole width of the parent container but should only be as big as the "Join" text,

and  changed border of boxtest1 class,
why you are smiling brother?

Comment: oh yeah,no one forbidden to be happy but you are laughing on me.

Comment: would never do that :)

Answer (score 0):

**Replace your css with this css:**

```
.boxtest1 {
  height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 32px;
  width: 38%;
  border: 4px solid #ff5857;
  border-radius: 0px 40px 0px 40px;
  background: rgba(255,88,87,0.2);
}
#sbts {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #BDBDBD;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted #ff5857;
}
#sbtsinfo {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #BDBDBD;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted #ff5857;
}
#sbtsbutton {
  direction: rtl;
  padding:20px 15px;
}
#sbtsbutton a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #BDBDBD;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 2px solid #ff5857;
  border-radius: 0px 20px 0px 20px;

}
#sbtsbutton a:hover {
  background: #228822;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if I find you well,do this to get a better design

```html
<div class="boxtest1">
    <div id="sbts">
        TeamSpeak³
    </div>
    <div id="sbtsinfo">
        some text here <br> some more text <br> some more text
    </div>
    <div id="sbtsbutton">
        <a href="ts3server://xxxxx">Join</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
 
   .boxtest1 {
  height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 32px;
  width: 38%;
  border: 4px solid #ff5857;
  border-radius: 0px 40px 0px 40px;
  background: rgba(255,88,87,0.2);
/*my changes*/
  float:left;
  margin-left: 31%;
}
#sbtsbutton {
  direction: rtl;
  
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 2px solid #ff5857;
  border-radius: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
/*my changes*/
  float:right;
  padding:5px 20px;
}
```